# Cual es la manera correcta de agregar 3 puntos al final de cada elemento de un objeto

Tags: javascript

Tengo este siguiente objeto:

```
let userInformation = {
          description: "Esta es mi descripción",
          email: "prueba@gmail.com"
          full_name: "Josue Ayala"
          username: "jos"
          website: "es.stackoverflow.com/users/136931/josue-martinez"
      };
```

Cual es la manera correcta de aplicar el `substring` para agregar "`...`" al final de cada palabra después de 7 caracteres, en mi objeto para que mis elementos queden así:

```
let userInformation = {
              description: "Esta es..",
              email: "prueba@..."
              full_name: "Josue A..."
              username: "jos"
              website: "es.stac..."
          };
```

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
let textTrunc = text.map(item => {
  return {
    description: `${item.description.substring(0, 14)}...`,
    email: `${item.email.substring(0, 14)}...`,
    etc
  };
});
```

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres hacer es usar esos datos para ponerlos en algun contenedor, contenedor el cual dependiendo de la cantidad de informacion o digitos o si depronto no cabe en el contenedor, en vez de dividirse en otra linea mostrara `...` supongo yo entonces que si tu idea es realmente esa entonces no lo hagas desde javascript, ya que puedes tener la informacion completa en javascript y acomodar eso con solamente `HTML` y `CSS`, si quieres puedes ir investigando acerca de `text-overflow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @BetaM Ya actualize lo que e intentado.

Comment: @JosueMartinez La verdad que yo reformularia la pregunta, porque no creo que haya **una forma correcta**, quizás haya alguna mas eficiente que otra...

Comment: @Marcos tiene razon, el titulo de la pregunta roza el ambito basado en opiniones.

Comment: @Riven Lo logre asi como tu me lo dijiste igual, ocupe algunas propiedades de bootstrap: `class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que muestras no es un array sino un objeto, pero según lo que te entiendo puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Iterar el objeto con clave, valor
2. Cambiar el valor por cada iteración

---

```js
let userInformation = {
  description: "Esta es mi descripción",
  email: "prueba@gmail.com",
  full_name: "Josue Ayala",
  username: "jos",
  website: "es.stackoverflow.com/users/136931/josue-martinez"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userInformation)) {
  if (value.length >= 7) {
    userInformation[key] = value.substring(0, 7) + "...";
  }
}
console.log(userInformation)
```

Comment: Pues... esto funcionaria pero estarias creando un objeto nuevo cada vez no se si el usuario quiera mas bien reemplazar la informacion, pero pues habra que esperar a ver si esto es enrealidad lo que desea el usuario... por lo pronto solo dire que esto puede funcionar.

Comment: @JosueMartinez te recomiendo que igual leas el comentario que deje en la pregunta, quiza si lo que yo pienso que es para lo que vas a usar esa informacion entonces es buena idea que leas sobre `text-overflow` de `css`.

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda que si esa respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darla como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo, asi le ayudaras a la persona que se tomo el tiempo de responderte (Gerardo Flores).

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa el objeto donde vas a almacenar los textos truncados, recorre el objeto original, analizando la longitud de la cadena y, si es mayor de 7, la truncas, de lo contrario, se queda el valor original.

```js
let userInformation = {
          description: "Esta es mi descripción",
          email: "prueba@gmail.com",
          full_name: "Josue Ayala",
          username: "jos",
          website: "es.stackoverflow.com/users/136931/josue-martinez"
};
// Inicializar objeto nuevo
let textTrunc = {};
for(let key in userInformation) {
    // Si el valor es mayor de 7 caracteres
    textTrunc[key] = (userInformation[key].length > 7)
        // Truncar y agregar puntos suspensivos
        ? userInformation[key].substring(0,7) + '...'
        // Valor sin modificar
        : userInformation[key];
}
console.log(textTrunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let userInformation = {
          description: "Esta es mi descripción",
          email: "prueba@gmail.com",
          full_name: "Josue Ayala",
          username: "jos",
          website: "es.stackoverflow.com/users/136931/josue-martinez"
      };
```

En primera debemos obtener los valores del objeto y lo convertimos a un array

```
 var toArray=Object.values(userInformation);
```

Iteramos sobre el array aplicando el substring al valor

```
 var newArr = toArray.map(function(val, index){ 

 return  `${val.substring(0, 7)}...`; 
        }) 
          
 console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!